# discord.py @client.command() doesn't seem to work

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to switch my bot from using @client.event for everything to also using @client.command
The problem is when running the command **.commandtest**, nothing happens. I put a print statement in the code to see if the problem was writing in the discord channel, but it doesn't print to the terminal either.

```
from discord.ext import commands
import os
import requests
import asyncio
import ctx


from keep_alive import keep_alive

client = discord.Client()

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")
client.remove_command('help')


@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))



@client.command()
async def commandtest(ctx):
  print("command worked?")
  await ctx.send('this is a test for commandtext')




keep_alive()
client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Comment: If you don't remove the help command, does *that* work?

Comment: Do you have an `on_message` event that you didn't include?

Answer (score 1):

The thing is I think we need to read docs, in there its written that on_message stops commands from working , So we should use `await client.process_commands(message)` At the end of client.event and it will work for sure

Comment: Hi, Is your answer directly hadnling the question? If this is a suggestion or proposal to solve the proposal to solve the, then please move this answer to a comment on the post.

Comment: yes it directly Handles it and writing this at the end of @client.event will make it work

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()
```

When, the bot is ready, it prints out that he's logged in

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as ' + str(client.user))
```

If you get a message in discord, that starts with '.', send the test message

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('.'):
        await message.channel.send('this is a test for commandtext')


client.run('YOUR TOKEN')
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need both `client = discord.Client()` and `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")` You would have to delete `client = discord.Client()` for the command to work. Also, you do not need `import ctx` because it is already imported in `from discord.ext import commands`. That should be the problem with your code. If you run into any other problems you could reply to this thread.